# How to run output of a string as PHP script?

Tags: php

I have a field in a database which contains the value :

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;!--? echo get_block(\&#039;contact\&#039;);?--&gt;&amp;lt;?php echo get_block(&amp;#39;home-page&amp;#39;); ?&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

When I am fetching the record in the front end, it just shows the output as a string:

```
echo $var = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($row_content_list["content"]));
```

**Output**

```
"<?php echo get_block('home-page');?>"
```

I want it to act as a PHP script.

Comment: why are you storing php in the db? - It is almost always a bad idea

Comment: Why are you storing HTML with embedded PHP code in an HTML entity encoded form with added slashes in the database?! It's mind bogglingly terrible!

Comment: ^^ i was to scared to mention the other issues :-)

Comment: You shouldn't store PHP in the database. If you really wanted to though I guess you could use the eval() function but this is always HIGHLY discouraged.

Comment: the simple solution is to eval($var) it. but thats ugly and unsecure. why has the database those values in the first place? can you change the database to hold real values without code?

Comment: And technically eval() won't work with the <?php ?> tags in place.

Comment: Y have you asked the same question multiple times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173473/echo-a-string-in-php-that-contains-or-php-and-a-php-function

Comment: If that had been the case the answers wouldn't be different . Anyways read it carefully the questions are different.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add it as a PHP script.

PHP = Server-side language, it PROCESSES your given commands and throws an HTML output. (ofc with errors at times) You cannot re-process an already processed output.

Once you fetch from database it is processed already. Secondly, you cannot echo and expected PHP function to be executed. because ECHO itself is a php (system) *thing*.

You might want to re-strategize your approach.

EDIT: Don't use eval. Especially when things are coming out from database unless and until you are SUPER SURE about your data sanitization.

Comment: Will downvoter please explain how this answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create .php file like this `$filename = 'script.php'`

```
$openedFile = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");      
        fwrite($openedFile, $var);      
        fclose($openedFile);
```

write there your `$var` and then include it...It could work :) but still not secure

Comment: **+1** ... This is the only way I can think of to make this work, despite the fact that it is **NOT RECOMMENDED**, and also **MAY PUT YOUR ENTIRE SERVER AT RISK**.  On the other hand, more stuff like this means more work for skilled consultants, so I guess we shouldn't make too much of a fuss...

Comment: How's that different from `eval`, besides the fact that it's much slower and messier?

Comment: for `eval` The code mustn't be wrapped in opening and closing PHP tags, i.e. 'echo "Hi!";' must be passed instead of '<? echo "Hi!"; >'.

Comment: Well, it's really not hard to work around that: `eval("?>$code<?php")`

Comment: OK, make that [`eval("?>$code<?php;")`](http://codepad.org/qjNZpo87).

Answer (score 0):

You should try [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function ,it accept's a string and reflect's PHP from it.

The only thing to mention is ,you should remove `<?php ?>` tag's.

```
$var= html_entity_decode(stripslashes($row_content_list["content"]));
eval($var);
```